# Force "respond_do" format

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, format

I am using RJS with Prototype. In my controller I have this code:

```
def method_name
    respond_to do |format|
        ...
        format.html
        format.js
    end
en
```

Is it possible to force the "respond_do" to use the 'format.html' whether or no the request is HTML or JAVA? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use respond_to.  Just let the controller action return or call render if you want to specify a particular view.